# Insert images into Word document from folder

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a working macro that inserts 6 images into a Word document from a folder. I am not able to adjust the macro for more than 6 images.

```vb
Sub InsertScreenshotsWithCustomText()
    Dim myFolder As String, myFile As String
    myFolder = "path\to\folder\images\stored" 'Change this to the path of your folder
    myFile = Dir(myFolder & "*.jpg") 'Change ".jpg" to the file extension of your screenshots. This can be changed to ".png", ".jpeg", etc.
    
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim rowCount As Integer
    Dim colCount As Integer
    rowCount = 1
    colCount = 1
    
    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=6, NumColumns:=2)
    tbl.AllowAutoFit = True ' Allow the table to automatically adjust column width
    
    Do While Len(myFile) > 0
        Dim pic As InlineShape
        Set pic = tbl.Cell(rowCount, colCount).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=myFolder & myFile, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
        pic.Height = InchesToPoints(2)
        pic.Width = tbl.Cell(rowCount, colCount).Width - 4 ' Set the image width to fit the column and leave a small margin
        
        Dim customText As String
        customText = InputBox("Enter text below the image (Image " & rowCount & "):", "Custom Text", "Enter your text here")
        tbl.Cell(rowCount + 1, colCount).Range.Text = customText
        tbl.Cell(rowCount + 1, colCount).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter ' Center the text
        
        colCount = colCount + 1 ' Move to the next column for the next image
        
        If colCount > 2 Then ' If we have reached the end of the row, move to the next row
            colCount = 1
            rowCount = rowCount + 2
        End If
        
        If rowCount > 6 Then
            Exit Do ' Exit loop if we have reached the last row
        End If
        
        myFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

The format I would like the word document to be in:

| Col 1 | Col 2 |
| --- | --- |
| Image 1 | Image 4 |
| text | text |
| Image 2 | Image 5 |
| text | text |
| Image 3 | Image 6 |
| text | text |

I tried to modify the code. I expected it to insert another table with images 7 - 12 and letters beneath it.

Comment: See: https://www.msofficeforums.com/drawing-and-graphics/49547-automate-insertion-multiple-images-into-document.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code is hard-coded to only have 6 rows. You can adjust the number of rows by changing the following two lines (replace 6 with the number of rows you require, keeping in mind that it needs to be a multple of 2)

```
Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=6, NumColumns:=2)
```

And

```
If rowCount > 6 Then
```

Alternatively, the following will (should) work for as many images as `Dir` returns. (it doesn't do pages so no idea what happens when it gets too long!)

```
Sub Main()

Dim Path As String: Path = "Your\Path\"

Dim File As String: File = Dir(Path & "*.jpg")

Dim T As Table
Set T = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=2, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitContent)
Dim Row As Integer: Row = 1
Dim Column As Integer: Column = 1

Do While Len(File) > 0
    Dim Image As String: Image = Path & File
    
    Dim Pic As InlineShape
    Set Pic = T.C7ell(Row:=Row, Column:=Column).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=Image, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
    
    Pic.Height = InchesToPoints(2)
    Pic.Width = T.Cell(Row:=Row, Column:=Column).Width - 4
    
    Dim Text As String
    Text = InputBox("Enter Text for <" & Image & ">")
    T.Cell(Row:=Row + 1, Column:=Column).Range.Text = Text
    T.Cell(Row:=Row + 1, Column:=Column).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    

    File = Dir
    
    If Column = 1 Then
        Column = 2
    Else
        Column = 1
        Row = Row + 2
        
        If Len(File) > 0 Then
            T.Rows.Add
            T.Rows.Add
        End If
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did try this out. However, I had a question. So it inserts the images as such:
image 1 | image 2
image 3 | image 4

How would you modify this to be:
image 1 | image 3
image 2 | image 4

Also for more than 6 images, the order of inserting changes, and instead of inserting in order of appearance in the folder, it inserts randomly. Do you know if there is a way to fix this?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, other than image 2 and 3 being reversed in the text. Update your question to show your desired output. The order of the images is determined by `Dir` and I dont know if there is a way to sort that without pre-reading all the results and sorting them manually.

Comment: I have modified the question as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This will add a new table when the original one is full:

```vb
Sub InsertScreenshotsWithCustomText()
    
    Const PICS_FOLDER As String = "C:\Temp\VBA\Folder1\" 'Change this to the path of your folder
    
    Dim myFile As String, customText As String
    Dim tbl As Table, rowCount As Long, colCount As Long
    
    rowCount = 1
    colCount = 1
    
    SetTable Selection.Range, tbl  'get the first table
    
    myFile = Dir(PICS_FOLDER & "*.jpg")
    Do While Len(myFile) > 0
        
        With tbl.Cell(rowCount, colCount).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture( _
                      FileName:=PICS_FOLDER & myFile, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
            .Height = InchesToPoints(2)
            .Width = tbl.Cell(rowCount, colCount).Width - 4
        End With
        
        customText = myFile 'InputBox("Enter text below the image (Image " & rowCount & "):", "Custom Text", "Enter your text here")
        
        With tbl.Cell(rowCount + 1, colCount).Range
            .Text = customText
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
        End With
        
        colCount = colCount + 1
        
        If colCount > tbl.Columns.Count Then
            colCount = 1
            rowCount = rowCount + 2
        End If
        
        If rowCount > tbl.Rows.Count Then
            SetTable Nothing, tbl 'next table
            rowCount = 1
            colCount = 1
        End If
        
        myFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub

'get the initial table (positioned at `rng`)
'  or create a new table after existing table `tbl`
Sub SetTable(rng As Range, ByRef tbl As Table)
    Const TBL_ROWS As Long = 6
    Const TBL_COLS As Long = 2
    If Not tbl Is Nothing Then  'is there already a table? Insert another below it
        Set rng = tbl.Range
        rng.Collapse WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
        rng.Move WdUnits.wdCharacter, 1
        rng.InsertParagraph
        rng.InsertParagraph
        rng.Collapse WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
    End If
    
    Set tbl = rng.Parent.Tables.Add(Range:=rng, NumRows:=TBL_ROWS, NumColumns:=TBL_COLS)
    tbl.AllowAutoFit = True ' Allow the table to automatically adjust column width
End Sub
```